# Hook to when external window is moved to another desktop

Tags: winapi, hook, virtual-desktop

How can I receive a message when user moves somebody else's window between Windows 10 virtual desktops?

I am currently using [SetWinEventHook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for all other similar purposes (like tracking minimization, text change, etc), but there does not seem to be an entry for moving between virtual desktops in [the documentation for event types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318066(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @RbMm, I am sorry if it was not clear, but the question is about Windows 10 virtual desktops. AFAIK, user can't move an existing window to a different "Desktop" of the kind that you mentioned.

Comment: @LOST I don't think there is a specific event for this issue. Virtual Desktops is a fairly new feature, maybe MS simply overlooked exposing events related to it. However, there is an [`IVirtualDesktopManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt186440.aspx) interface, which has [`GetWindowDesktopId()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt186441.aspx) and [`IsWindowOnCurrentDesktop()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt186442.aspx) methods, so you should be able to cobble together some kind of manual window tracking system.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thanks for the idea, that's what I ended up doing for now. Polling has its disadvantages though: you need to spend processor cycles and your app needs a context switch for it.